# Looking for example of use of mutex threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am learning `pthreads` and `mutex variables` specifically.  I am looking at an example code that you can find [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes).  It uses threads to compute a dot product.  The central part of the code is the dot product function:

```
 void *dotprod(void *arg)
 {


    int i, start, end, len ;
    long offset;
    double mysum, *x, *y;
    offset = (long)arg;
     
    len = dotstr.veclen;
    start = offset*len;
    end   = start + len;
    x = dotstr.a;
    y = dotstr.b;


    mysum = 0;
    for (i=start; i<end ; i++) 
     {
       mysum += (x[i] * y[i]);
     }

    /*
    Lock a mutex prior to updating the value in the shared
    structure, and unlock it upon updating.
    */
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
    dotstr.sum += mysum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);

    pthread_exit((void*) 0);
 }
```

First question is whether locking the threads here is really necessary.  I tried removing the lock and unlock calls, and the end result was the same.  But, it's just an example, so maybe in practice the locks are not needed.  Which brings me to my second question: I thought I would try to alter the code to something whose output would might change depending on whether multiple threads were accessing `dotstr.sum`.  I got rid of the lock again and tried:

```
dotstr.sum += mysum;
dotstr.sum *= 1.1;
```

But contrary to my expectations, this did not introduce a race condition.  The output was exactly the same in several trials.  Why would this be?  Finally, can someone suggest a simple alteration to the code where a lock would be necessary?

Comment: Unsynchronised access results in Undefined Behaviour. You can't have expectation of any particular behaviour for any particular run (e.g. instantly break every time).

Comment: "race condition" does not mean that the threads _did_ interfere with each other. It means that it is _possible_ for the threads to interfere with each other.

Comment: Just as a side note: The line `offset = (long)arg;` will not work on some platforms, such as Microsoft Windows, where `sizeof(long) == 4` and `sizeof(void*) == 8`. You may want to consider using [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) instead of `long`, as that type has been defined by the standard specifically for holding the same amount of bits as a pointer.

Comment: There is always the possibility that one thread will be preempted (i.e. stop running) in a critical situation, so that another thread wins the race. If you want to reproduce this situation, then you may want to add random behavior into the faster thread, for example `if (rand()%100==0) DoSomethingWhichCostsALotOfPerformance();`

Comment: [Look here](https://godbolt.org/z/fc1MTd).